# Encrypt / Decrypt an array into a single number

Tags: arrays, encryption

I needed a way to convert a single dimensional array into a single number. For example, for a given array, `arr`.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I need a function to encrypt `arr` into a number `n`

```
encrypt(arr) = n
```

Such that I can decrypt the number `n` back into my original `arr`

```
decrypt(n) = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Each element of `arr` are is ≥ 0 and < 128. Would such an algorithm be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such an algorithm is possible.  For example, [Gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering).  Your array [1, 2, 3, 4] would be encoded as: 2^1 * 3^2 * 5^3 * 7^4 = 5,402,250.  Use the prime factorisation of that number to retrieve the array.  Be warned that Gödel numbering can get very large very quickly as your array gets longer.